# Why is knockoutjs not binding correctly?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Why isn't [this code](http://jsfiddle.net/6SuQJ/7/) not changing after 3 seconds? What am I doing wrong?

```
<div data-bind="visible: isBusy()">
is busy
</div>

<div data-bind="visible: !isBusy()">
is not busy
</div>



var viewModel;
function AppViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.isBusy = ko.observable(true);
}

function isNotBusyAnymore() {
    viewModel.isBusy = ko.observable(true);
}

viewModel = new AppViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
setTimeout(isNotBusyAnymore, 3000);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you keep making a new observable....and also your function always sets it to "true"

```
function isNotBusyAnymore() {
    viewModel.isBusy(false);
}
```

Comment: wow! One of those gotchas that drove me crazy! I guess I've been in front of the computer for way too long! Thanks!

Comment: yeah, I know those days.....  I tend to use coffeescript with knockout these days,  I was having a similar DOH moment with some knockout binding stuff today!